# Assertion Failed, ember routes with dynamic id

Tags: ember.js, routes

i try to build an web app with ember, i use a routing model with :post_id but that doesn't work:
http://www.wilhelminaschool.eu/app2/#posts works and shows a list but
links to #post/11330 not working, Error: Assertion Failed?

what i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

change your router map to

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route("page");
    this.route("menu");
    this.resource('posts', function(){
      this.resource('post', { path: '/:post_id' });
    )};
    this.route("index", { path: "/" });
    this.route("cat");
    this.route("foto");
});
```

Comment: then i get "The route post/11330 was not found"

Comment: you should not visit post/11330. It should be posts/11330

Comment: Already solved it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23211617/ember-route-not-found/23212169?noredirect=1#23212169