# Ember route not found

Tags: ember.js, routes

i try to build an webapp with emberjs. this is the app router:

```
    App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route("page");
    this.route("menu");
    this.resource('posts', function(){
      this.resource('post', { path: '/:post_id' });
    });
    this.route("index", { path: "/" });
    this.route("cat");
    this.route("foto");
});
```

and this is the Postroute:

```
// GET POST JSON
App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return Ember.$.getJSON('http://www.wilhelminaschool.eu/?json=get_post&post_id='+params.post_id);
  }
});
```

but i get an route not found error for the post, the posts list works. What i am doing wrong?

error:
Error: Assertion Failed: The route post/11330 was not found

live on:
http://www.wilhelminaschool.eu/app2/#posts
http://www.wilhelminaschool.eu/app2/#post/11330

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each one of the posts links to `app2/#post/:post_id` i.e. `app2/#post/11330` , but since the `post` resource has been defined within the resource of `posts` with a path of `/:post_id` the links should be `app2/#/posts/:post_id` i.e. `app2/#/posts/11330`

example,

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/budeyaja/1/edit

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/budeyaja/1  (*please observe the urls while navigating*)

If you need the links to work as they are then the routes will have to be specified as ,

```
this.resource("posts");
this.resource("post", {path:"/post/:post_id"});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qaquzusi/1/edit

Comment: @heidemanmedia there is one more wrong thing in your code. You named your code as `App.PostRoute` but as per route naming conventions routes are named as resourcename then route name thus in your code route should be named as `App.PostsPostRoute`

Comment: @guleria if you look at the example of `comments` in http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_nested-resources which is a nested resource, the name of the corresponding route is `App.CommentsRoute` . The case where the namespace need to be preserved in nested resources, is shown on the following example with the resource named `foo.bar`. So i think the code is ok.

Comment: Ohh you are right I misread the code I thought inner one was route but it is a resource.

Answer (score 0):

Do not nest the post resource inside posts, use:

```
 this.resource('posts');
 this.resource('post', { path: '/post/:post_id' });
```

[Ember Routing Guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/) provides a clear explanation of different cases.